# Is it possible to get all OSM nodes (are not belong to any way) using the Overpass API?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I want to get all OSM nodes (are not belong to any way).
Is it possible?

Understandably, this query get all nodes (includes member of ways)...

```
<osm-script output="json">
    <query type="node">
      <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
    </query>
    <print/>
</osm-script>
```

**Update 19 Sep 20:20(GMT+9:00)**

I tried tyr's query and success!

[image]

Comment: I don't see a possible query to achieve this but of course you could post-filter the data. Can you explain us why you need such a strange query?

Comment: I just developing Android OSM editer app, like a Pushpin OSM.
Of course, it must get all areas and nodes finally (release ver. app).
But now developing, I thought "Show only nodes are more easy than show areas and nodes"...

Comment: Then I suggest to post-filter the data returned by the Overpass API and remove all nodes which belong to at least one way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, this is possible since the latest version of Overpass API:

```
<osm-script output="json">
  <query type="way">
    <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
  </query>
  <recurse type="way-node" into="waynodes"/>
  <query type="node" into="allnodes">
    <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
  </query>
  <difference>
    <item set="allnodes"/>
    <item set="waynodes"/>
  </difference>
  <print/>
</osm-script>
```

http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/14F

This uses the `difference` operator to subtract nodes that are member of any ways from all of the nodes.